# A basic question on Ohm’s law and the definition of voltage

Tags: ohms-law

1 Volt is defined as: when 1 Joule of work is expended in moving 1 Coulomb charge between two points.

On the other hand the Ohm’s law states:

V = I × R

I draw a theoretical circuit below where an ideal 1V voltage source is coupled to a 1 Ohm resistor.

[image]

From these two definitions is it possible to estimate the total charge moved between A and B when the supply is 1V and the resistance is 1 Ohm?

Seems like time is confusing me because Joule is energy unit. Watt joule eV voltage resistance all mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amps is coulombs/second. 1 coulomb  6.242×10e18 electrons, if you want to find out how many electrons, find how many seconds and multiply it by how many amps are flowing through the resistor. This gives you coulombs, to find the number of elections, multiply it by 6.242×10e18 .

Joules is watts·second. If you know how many secconds and how many watts, you can determine how much charge has gone through the resistor.

It should be easy to tell how many watts is going through the resistor given the above diagram.

Comment: 1Vx1A=1W. So can we say per second 1 C charge moves between A and B? And can we estimate the number of electrons from that? 1 coulomb = 6.242 × 10^18 electrons

Comment: @panicattack and what about Q=i*t

Comment: Watts are joules/second.

Comment: Tell me some quantity I need to veriify whether I got it. Is my first comment correct?

Comment: Thought you were trying to find joules, I also interluded the calc for electrons

Comment: @laptop2d What actually moves from A to B in a second not individual electrons but the charge correct?

Comment: Joules are watt seconds. OP wants charge moved, not watts or electrons.

Comment: @panic: The electromagnetic wave travels at a speed close to that of light. Meanwhile the electron drift will be measured in mm/s depending on the current density (current divided by conductor cross-sectional area). That means, effectively, that an electron gets pushed in at one end and a different one gets pushed out at the other but almost immediately.

Answer (score -1):

The 1V source *continuously* imparts a joule on each coulomb as it moves between the plates, according to \$V=\frac{J}{C}\$. Think of it like having a pile of balls at a certain height - each ball has potential energy thanks to it being at that height. Similarly, each coulomb in the voltage source has the potential of 1V. How frequently the coulombs move (*fall from their height*) is dictated by the resistor, according to \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$.

So for \$V=1\$ and \$R=1\$ there is \$I=\frac{V}{R}=1\$ coulomb per second moving between **A** and **B**.

The volt equation gives us no further information: it simply says that the work done in moving each of those coulombs is \$J=VC=1\$ joule. Since there is 1 coulomb moving per second, there is 1 joule of work being done each second, which is called a watt. This is verified by the power equation: \$P = \frac{V^2}{R} = 1\$ watt. Change \$V\$ to 2 and the maths still works out.

Note that I use *move* in a colloquial sense. Charge is technically *transferred* and describing it as a *move* is not strictly correct, but a useful analogy for clarity.